# How many $3$-tuples are there, if each element of the tuple is a non-empty subset of the same set?

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

> Given set $D=\{0,1,2,3\}$ and a set $C$ of $n$ elements how many $3$-tuples of type $(C_1, C_2, C_3)$ can be found such that $C_1, C_2, C_3$ are non-empty, disjoint subsets of $C$.
>
> Hint: To each $3$-tuple $(C_1, C_2, C_3)$ assign a function $g$ from $C$ to $D$ such that $g(x) = i$ if $x\in C_i$ where $1\le i\le 3$ and $g(x) =0$ otherwise.

When I think about the problem I think about making 3 non-empty partitions within $C$ and then permuting the partitioned subsets. There're:
$$
{3-1+n\choose n}={n+2 \choose n}
$$
possibilities to partition $C$ into $3$ partitions without the restriction that $C_i: |C_i|\ge1$. With the restriction there're:
$$
{3-1+n-3\choose n-3}={n-1 \choose n-3}
$$
subsets of $C$.

Because the subsets are elements of an ordered $3$-tuple we need to permute them, so the final answer is:
$$
{n-1 \choose n-3}\cdot 3!
$$

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track and if I am why do we need that hint about assigning functions.

Comment: Your solution is incomprehensible. The word "partition" has a definite meaning in mathematics, but you are using it to mean something else, not sure what. Moreover, your final answer is wrong for $n\gt3.$ E.g., when $n=4,$ there are many more than $18$ solutions; in fact there are $24$ triples if we count only those with $C_1,C_2,C_3$ all $1$-element sets. Apparently you do need the hint; followed up properly it may lead you to the correct answer.

Comment: @bof perhaps my usage of "partition" is not appropriate for this problem, I meant that to solve the problem is equivalent to the number of ways to distribute $n$ objects into $3$ bins which is combination with repetition. but then because the subsets are ordered I thought we just need to permute them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the function $g$ is defined, we can define the subset $C_i$ as $g^{-1}(i)$ for $i=1,2,3$ and we get a 3-tuple of disjoint subsets. Thus we need to count the number of ways of assigning the integers $0,1,2,3$ to the $n$ elements of $C$ such that we assign each of $1, 2, 3$ to at least one element of $C$. This can be done using the Principle of Inclusion Exclusion.

The total number of ways of assigning $0,1,2,3$ is $4^n$. Of these, in $3^n$ of these, 1 is missing, $3^n$ of these 2 is missing and in $3^n$ of these, 3 will be missing. Similarly 2 of $0,1,2,3$ will be missing in $2^n$ and all three will be missing in 1 of the assignments. Thus the required number of functions $g$ is 
$$4^n - \binom{3}{1}3^n + \binom{3}{2}2^n - \binom{3}{3}1^n$$

Comment: What if I needed to choose 3 non-empty and disjoint subsets but this time order is not important? Would it be ${n-1 \choose n-3}$ this time?

Comment: No. $\frac{1}{3!}\left(4^n-\binom{3}{1}3^n + \binom{3}{2}2^n-\binom{3}{3}1^n\right)$

Comment: Is it because in the problem where order is important we also permute the 3 subsets, so if order is not important we just need to divide the previous solution by $3!$ in order to remove permuting?

Comment: Yes. you are right. If you want $k$ disjoint subsets, the answer would be $\frac{1}{k!}((k+1)^n - \binom{k}{1} k^n + \cdots )$.